# Bash: splitting a list of strings each containing space-separated words in different variables for each word

Tags: bash, fail2ban

I'm trying to parse the **apache error log** to grep the lines that corresponds to the "offending" IPs found in the **fail2ban** log.

I'm using a script in **bash**.

First I extract the offending IPs:

```
offenders=$(grep -F "[apache-errors] Found" /var/log/fail2ban.log | awk '{print $8}' | sort | uniq)
```

Then for each IP I get the entries from the fail2ban.log; there may be multiple entries, because the IP may have done requests at multiple times:

```
for ip in $offenders; do
    entries=$(grep -F "[apache-errors] Found $ip" /var/log/fail2ban.log | awk '{print $8" "$10" "$11}' | sort | uniq)
 
    declare _count_entries=$(echo "${entries[@]}" | wc -l)
    echo "Found $_count_entries error entries for IP $ip"

    for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do
        echo "$entry"
    done
done
```

This is what I get so far (IPs have been anonymized):

```
[INFO] Found 1 error entries for IP 10.10.0.29
10.10.0.29 2021-12-20 06:33:12
[INFO] Found 2 error entries for IP 10.20.0.242
10.20.0.242 2021-12-21 10:51:44
10.20.0.242 2021-12-30 12:03:55
[INFO] Found 3 error entries for IP 10.30.0.186
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:20:49
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:40:24
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 07:38:55
```

Now what I want to do is, for *each* line extract the ip, date and time portions. I tried something like this, but **IT DOES NOT WORK**, it prints only the (ip,date,time) for the first `entry`:

```
for ip in $offenders; do
    entries=$(grep -F "[apache-errors] Found $ip" /var/log/fail2ban.log | awk '{print $8" "$10" "$11}' | sort | uniq)
    
    for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do

        echo "$entry"

        _ip=($(echo "$entry" | cut -d ' ' -f1))
        _date=($(echo "$entry" | cut -d ' ' -f2))
        _time=($(echo "$entry" | cut -d ' ' -f3))
        echo "ip=$_ip , date=$_date , time=$_time"

    done
done
```

Output: for each entry, only the (ip,date,time) portions of the first one is echoed:

```
[INFO] Found 1 error entries for IP 10.10.0.29
10.10.0.29 2021-12-20 06:33:12
ip=10.10.0.29 , date=2021-12-20 , time=06:33:12
[INFO] Found 2 error entries for IP 10.20.0.242
10.20.0.242 2021-12-21 10:51:44
10.20.0.242 2021-12-30 12:03:55
ip=10.20.0.242 , date=2021-12-21 , time=10:51:44
[INFO] Found 3 error entries for IP 10.30.0.186
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:20:49
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:40:24
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 07:38:55
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=05:20:49
```

The desired output would be:

```
[INFO] Found 1 error entries for IP 10.10.0.29
10.10.0.29 2021-12-20 06:33:12
ip=10.10.0.29 , date=2021-12-20 , time=06:33:12
[INFO] Found 2 error entries for IP 10.20.0.242
10.20.0.242 2021-12-21 10:51:44
10.20.0.242 2021-12-30 12:03:55
ip=10.20.0.242 , date=2021-12-21 , time=10:51:44
ip=10.20.0.242 , date=2021-12-30 , time=12:03:55
[INFO] Found 3 error entries for IP 10.30.0.186
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:20:49
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 05:40:24
10.30.0.186 2022-01-02 07:38:55
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=05:20:49
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=05:40:24
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=07:38:55
```

So how can I do that in bash?

The final goal is to use the ip, date and time portions to build a regex like this, because I want to grep the lines from the error logs that correspond exactly to the findings in the fail2ban log:

```
grep -P "^(\[$_date $_time)(.+\[client )($_ip).+$" /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: `"${entries[@]}"` implies `entries` to be an array but `entries=$(...)` doesn't create an array.

Comment: Are you sure that you want `10.10.0.29 2021-12-20 06:33:12` **AND**
`ip=10.10.0.29 , date=2021-12-20 , time=06:33:12`?

Comment: Why would you want both the raw and formatted version of `10.10.0.29 2021-12-20 06:33:12`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @M.NejatAydin

Comment: @konsolebox I actually need to have the IP, date and time in three separate variables in order to use them in a regex, see my final goal at the bottom of the question. Printing out either raw or fomatted is not my ultimate goal, but it was functional to the keeping the question simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
  
print_errors() {
  local ip=$1
  [ -n "$ip" ] || return
  shift
  echo "[INFO] Found ${#@} error entries for IP $ip"
  printf '%s\n' "$@"
}

prev_ip=
errors=()
while read -r ip date time
do
    if [ "$prev_ip" != "$ip" ]
    then
        print_errors "$prev_ip" "${errors[@]}"
        prev_ip=$ip
        errors=()
    fi
    errors+=("ip=$ip , date=$date , time=$time")
done < <(
    grep -F "[apache-errors] Found" /var/log/fail2ban.log |
    awk '{print $8" "$10" "$11}' |
    sort
)

print_errors "$prev_ip" "${errors[@]}"
```

But bash is not really meant for that, it's better to write the same logic with `awk` (I'm doing the sorting outside of awk here):

```sh
grep -F "[apache-errors] Found" /var/log/fail2ban.log | sort -k 8,1 |
awk '
    function print_errors(ip, arr) {
        if (ip == "") return
        print "[INFO] Found "length(arr)" error entries for IP "ip
        for (i in arr) print arr[i]
    }
    BEGIN { ip = "" }
    {
        if ($8 != ip) {
            print_errors(ip, arr)
            delete arr
            ip = $8
        }
        arr[length(arr)+1] = "ip="$8" , date="$10" , time="$11
    }
    END{ print_errors(ip, arr) }
'
```

Or even better, write the whole thing in a language that has multidimensional associative arrays and text processing facilities:

Example with `ruby`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
  
ARGF.each_line.with_object(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |line,hash|
  ip,date,time = line.split.values_at(7,9,10)
  hash[ip] << "ip=#{ip} , date=#{date} , time=#{time}"
end.each do |ip,arr|
  puts "[INFO] Found #{arr.count} error entries for IP #{ip}"
  puts arr.join("\n")
end
```

---

output example of the three programs above:

```
[INFO] Found 1 error entries for IP 10.10.0.129
ip=10.10.0.129 , date=2021-12-20 , time=06:33:12
[INFO] Found 2 error entries for IP 10.20.0.242
ip=10.20.0.242 , date=2021-12-21 , time=10:51:44
ip=10.20.0.242 , date=2021-12-30 , time=12:03:55
[INFO] Found 3 error entries for IP 10.30.0.186
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=05:20:49
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=05:40:24
ip=10.30.0.186 , date=2022-01-02 , time=07:38:55
```

Comment: thank you, your answer pointed me to the right direction! I have used the `read` function in a slightly different implementation. And at last, I'm realizing I would better do this in another language, I do not know ruby unfortunately but I'm considering python.